# Error when I pass a different form of K in knearest neighbours(Sci kit learn)

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

When running k nearest neighbors in scikit learn, When I set k as 21 I get value error. but when I set k as `k=np.arange(20) +1` I dont get an error, so what is the difference between these two?

```
k = np.arange(21)

parameters = {'n_neighbors': k}
knn = sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier()

clf = sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV(knn, parameters, cv=10)
clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)

ValueError: Invalid shape in axis 1: 0.
```

Also can some one explain me what is the

```
a = clf.grid_scores_
scores = [b.cv_validation_scores for b in a]
```

Out put of scores is as follows :

```
array([ 1.        ,  0.90909091,  1.        ,  0.72727273,  0.9       ,
         1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  0.88888889]),
```

`clf.grid_scores_` is accuracy of the classifier but what is that `cv_validation` scores??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GridSearchCV` expects a list of values for each parameter to search over. If you want to set just one value for the search, put it into list:

```
parameters = {'n_neighbors': [21]} # ok
parameters = {'n_neighbors': np.range(21)} # error, the first value is 0
parameters = {'n_neighbors': np.range(21) + 1} # ok
```

Notice that each value in that list should be valid value for that parameter. For example, using `np.range(p)` as a list of parameters for `n_neighbors` is wrong since it has `0` which is invalid value for number of neighbors.

According to the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn-grid-search-gridsearchcv),

> `cv_validation_scores` [is] the list of scores for each fold

Thus `grid_scores_` must be averages of corresponding `cv_validation_scores`.

Comment: Can you precisely explain what these b.cv_validation_scores indicate? because I am still confused. I understood np.arange concept

Comment: @ElizabethSusanJoseph, [K-fold Cross Validation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29#k-fold_cross-validation) splits your data into `k` (in your case, `cv=10`) parts. Then it uses `k-1` of them as a train set and the rest as a test. This procedure (fold) is repeated `k` times, so each part is used both for train and for test. Thus `cv_validation_scores` contains scores on each part of these `k`, having the rest used for training.

Comment: def computeTestScores(test_x, test_y, clf, cv):
    kFolds = sklearn.cross_validation.KFold(test_x.shape[0], n_folds=cv)

    scores = []
    for _, test_index in kFolds:
        test_data = test_x[test_index]
        test_labels = test_y[test_index]
        scores.append(sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score(test_labels, clf.predict(test_data)))
    return scores

Comment: I am still confused, can you explain how does k fold cross validation apply in above code. I know I am asking stupid questions, but I am not able to understand

Comment: What do you mean by "how does ... apply"? The whole function above is an implementation of K-Fold cross-validation using [`KFold`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.KFold.html#sklearn.cross_validation.KFold) iterator from sklearn, which is used to generate indexes for train and test data.

Comment: I was working on that exercise(problem 2). (https://github.com/cs109/2014/tree/master/homework). Thanks a lot I got it. The only part where Iam confused is scores.append(sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score(test_labels, clf.predict(test_data))), It returns scores right. What does this scores indicate. This is the only part I am confused with

Comment: The score is [accuracy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision) of a classifier as measured on `test_data` whereas all of the rest data was used for training.

Comment: So [1,1,1,1, 0.90] means that a score (on a scale of 0-1)is  how well did my classifer perform am I right??

Comment: Thanks for this patient explanation.